# Serialize Kafka message into DB

Tags: python, sql, apache-kafka

What are best practice approaches of properly getting messages from Kafka and generating INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements for relational dbs using Python?

Say, I have events that Create Entity/Update Entity/Delete Entity and I want those messages to be transformed into relevant SQL script.

Is there any suggestion rather than writing serialization manually?

Comment: I would recommend to use Kafka Connect instead of writing your own Python application for this use case.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way around deserializing the record from Kafka and serializing into the appropriate database query. I would not recommend writing literal DDL statements as Kafka records and running those directly against a database client.

As commented, you can instead produce data in a supported format (JSONSchema, Avro, or Protobuf being the most common / well-documented) from Kafka Connect (optionally using a Schema Registry), then use a Sink Connector for your database.

Comment: I see only Amazon S3 Sink which loads data from Kafka to S3.  Also, most of https://docs.confluent.io/home/connect/self-managed/kafka_connectors.html are focused on getting data from DB to Kafka, but not vice-versa.